# Java - can not load a table from cassandra to a JavaRDD of spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

Trying to load a table in `cassandra` and create an `spark` data model so that I can process the data based on it. I have data already inserted into the `demokeyspace`(keyspace)' table `demotable`(cassandra table). Using codes below:

```
 JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    JavaRDD<String> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("demokeyspace", "demotable")
            .map(new Function<CassandraRow, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(CassandraRow cassandraRow) throws Exception {
                    return cassandraRow.toString();
                }
            });
    System.out.println("Data as CassandraRows: \n" + StringUtils.join(cassandraRowsRDD.toArray(), "\n"));
```

And it gives such errors:

```
14/11/24 14:49:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/11/24 14:49:56 INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@emsvm03.affirmed.local:60675/user/HeartbeatReceiver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.RowReaderFactory.targetClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.SparkContextJavaFunctions.cassandraTable(SparkContextJavaFunctions.java:91)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.SparkContextJavaFunctions.cassandraTable(SparkContextJavaFunctions.java:71)
at sparkDemo.SparkTest.run(SparkTest.java:28)
at sparkDemo.SparkTest.main(SparkTest.java:63)
```

The line `28` is

```
        JavaRDD<String> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("demokeyspace", "demotable")
```

But I am pretty sure that I have already insert data into the `demokeyspace.demotable`. So what's the issue?

Comment: There's a version issue with the spark-cassandra driver you are using. Probably the code have been compiled against a newer version than the one used to run it.